# Oracle ResultSetMetaData get opposite value from table

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have an ordinary table with members in some organization. I am using easy SQL script to get some records from member's table:

```sql
select ordinal,
   barcode,
   gender,
   to_char(m.m_birthdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') BIRTHDATE,
from members
```

Response in Intelij IDEA console:

[image: Oracle DB response]

In response we can see: Ordinal = 2

When we execute this request inside the program in this piece of code:

```java
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex<= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); columnIndex++) {
    String columnName = resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(columnIndex);
    String value = resultSet.getString(columnName);
    if (value == null) {
        value = "";
    }
}
```

We get: `resultSet.getString("Ordinal") = -2`

I can't figure out why the `ResultSet` returns -2 instead of 2. This is the situation with all members: -1 instead of 1, -6 instead of 6 and so on

All Resultset's  methods return negative value:

resulSet.getInt("Ordinal") = -2

resulSet.getDouble("Ordinal") = -2.0

resulSet.getFloat("Ordinal") = -2.0

I have an another user where in Oracle DB ORDINAL==1 and GENDER==1
And when we are trying execute same query we got:
ORDINAL== -1 and GENDER==1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4dEu.png)

Comment: Why should it be the same? The value isn't a string but an integer, so trying to get a string for a datatype that isn't does some conversion. Basically you are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: There is no public interface exposed for Interface:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api///java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html
So,  the value of this column can be not standard. 
We'd better call the interface method to implement your logic.

Comment: It could have something to do with the name, `ordinal`.  The solution could be as simple as changing your query to `select ordinal as ORD,`. You can always step into the `getInt("Ordinal")` call to find out why it's doing this.